# C#にてアプリからドラッグ&ドロップを受け入れたいのですが、FileContentsの結果がAll 0になってしまいます。

Tags: c#

C#でのドラッグ&ドロップによる他のアプリからのデータ取得は、以下に公開されているソースを流用しました。
[Outlook Drag and Drop in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C)

しかし、FileContentsの取得結果がAll 0になってしまいます。サイズは取得すべきサイズになっていて正しいです。
FORMATETC構造体に設定する.lindexメンバー変数の値が正しく設定されていないせいだとおもい、FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR構造体の.cItemsの値を設定してやってるんですが、やはりAll 0のままです。
何が悪いのかわかりません・・・

```
    case "FileContents":
    //override the default handling of FileContents which returns the
    //contents of the first file as a memory stream and instead return
    //a array of MemoryStreams containing the data to each file dropped

    //get the array of filenames which lets us know how many file contents exist

    // modified begin
    //string[] fileContentNames = (string[])this.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
    string[] fileContentNames = (string[])this.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");     // Unicode UTF-16LE
    if (fileContentNames.Length <= 0)
        fileContentNames = (string[])this.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");

    //create a MemoryStream array to store the file contents
    MemoryStream[] fileContents = new MemoryStream[fileContentNames.Length];

    //loop for the number of files acording to the file names
    for(int fileIndex = 0;fileIndex < fileContentNames.Length;fileIndex++)
    {
        //get the data at the file index and store in array
        // modified begin
        //fileContents[fileIndex] = this.GetData(format, fileIndex);
        if (gFileGrpDescW != null)
        {
            fileContents[fileIndex] = this.GetData(format, (int)gFileGrpDescW.cItems);
        }
        else if (gFileGrpDescA != null)
        {
            fileContents[fileIndex] = this.GetData(format, (int)gFileGrpDescA.cItems);
        }
        // modified end
    }

    // added
    gFileGrpDescW = null;
    gFileGrpDescA = null;

    //return array of MemoryStreams containing file contents
    return fileContents;
```

なお、具体的なアプリというのはEvernoteなのですが、Evernoteのノートを開発アプリにドラッグ&ドロップされたら直接受け取りたいのです。
一応元のコードをほぼそのまま使用しています。なお、ドラッグ&ドロップ時に複数のノートをまとめてドラッグすると、一つのデータとして受け取りますのでコード中のループは1度しか行われません。
Evernoteからエクスプローラ上に複数のノートをドラッグ&ドロップしても、一つのファイルとして出力されます。

FileContentsの情報取得については、以下の情報を参考にしています。
[Shows how Email attachments can be dropped onto your own controls](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/email/article.php/c3381/Handling-Drag-and-Drop-of-Email-Attachments.htm)

しかし、前述の通りFileContentsがAll 0となってしまい、困っています。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: すみません、ひとつ勘違いがあり本来のコードに直しました。
FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORの中のFILEDESCRIPTORの要素番号とFileContentsが一致する必要があるようでした。ただ、それでもAll 0のままです。
fileContents[fileIndex] = this.GetData(format, fileIndex);

Answer (score 2):

EvernoteとOutlook Drag and Drop in C#の両方をダウンロードして試してみました。
Evernote側は複数のノートをドラッグしても１つ目しか送ってこないようで、受け側にはどうしようもなく感じました。
OutlookDataObjectクラスの方はアドレス計算を32bitで行っているために64bitで動作しなかったり、マネージ／アンマネージの扱いが何重にも回りくどく遠回りしている感を醸し出していたりはしますが、FileContents自体は取れていました。

試していて気づいたのは、１回のDrag & Dropで複数回読み出すと１回目の読み出しでIStreamが終端までseekされているため、２回目はまず先頭に戻す必要があります。
もし、オリジナルコードを残し、その後ろに書き足したりしているとそれが理由で読み出せないように見えるかもしれません。

---

ついでなのでドロップされたデータからファイル名とコンテンツを読み込むクラスを書いてみました。
`File.Get(e.Data)`で取り出せます。エラー処理はしてません。

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FILETIME = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME;
using IComDataObject = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject;
using IFormsDataObject = System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject;
using STATSTG = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG;

namespace Sayuri.IO {
    public class File {
        private File(string name, byte[] bytes) {
            Name = name;
            Bytes = bytes;
        }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Bytes { get; private set; }

        static readonly DataFormats.Format CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW = DataFormats.GetFormat("FileGroupDescriptorW");
        static readonly DataFormats.Format CFSTR_FILECONTENTS = DataFormats.GetFormat("FileContents");

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GlobalAlloc(int uFlags, int dwBytes);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GlobalFree(IntPtr hMem);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(IntPtr hMem);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GlobalSize(IntPtr hMem);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GlobalUnlock(IntPtr hMem);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct FILEDESCRIPTORW {
            public int dwFlags;
            public Guid clsid;
            public long sizel;
            public long pointl;
            public int dwFileAttributes;
            public FILETIME ftCreationTime;
            public FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
            public FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
            public int nFileSizeHigh;
            public uint nFileSizeLow;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
            public string cFileName;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW {
            public int cItems;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
            public FILEDESCRIPTORW[] fgd;
        }

        public static File[] Get(IFormsDataObject dataObject) {
            return Get((IComDataObject)dataObject);
        }

        public static File[] Get(IComDataObject dataObject) {
            var fileDescriptor = GetFileDescriptor(dataObject);
            return fileDescriptor.fgd.Select((fgd, i) => new File(fgd.cFileName, GetFileContent(dataObject, i))).ToArray();
        }

        static FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW GetFileDescriptor(IComDataObject dataObject) {
            var format = new FORMATETC {
                cfFormat = unchecked((short)CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW.Id),
                dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
                ptd = IntPtr.Zero,
                lindex = 0,
                tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL
            };
            STGMEDIUM medium;
            dataObject.GetData(ref format, out medium);
            Debug.Assert(medium.tymed == TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL && medium.unionmember != IntPtr.Zero && medium.pUnkForRelease == null);
            try {
                return Marshal.PtrToStructure<FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW>(GlobalLock(medium.unionmember));
            }
            finally {
                GlobalFree(medium.unionmember);
            }
        }

        static byte[] GetFileContent(IComDataObject dataObject, int i) {
            var format = new FORMATETC {
                cfFormat = unchecked((short)CFSTR_FILECONTENTS.Id),
                dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
                ptd = IntPtr.Zero,
                lindex = i,
                tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL | TYMED.TYMED_ISTREAM
            };
            STGMEDIUM medium;
            dataObject.GetData(ref format, out medium);
            Debug.Assert(medium.unionmember != IntPtr.Zero && medium.pUnkForRelease == null);
            switch (medium.tymed) {
                case TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL: {
                        var size = (long)GlobalSize(medium.unionmember);
                        Debug.Assert(size <= Int32.MaxValue);
                        var buffer = new byte[size];
                        Marshal.Copy(GlobalLock(medium.unionmember), buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        GlobalUnlock(medium.unionmember);
                        GlobalFree(medium.unionmember);
                        return buffer;
                    }
                case TYMED.TYMED_ISTREAM: {
                        var stream = (IStream)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(medium.unionmember);
                        Marshal.Release(medium.unionmember);
                        STATSTG statstg;
                        stream.Stat(out statstg, 0);
                        Debug.Assert(statstg.cbSize <= Int32.MaxValue);
                        var buffer = new byte[statstg.cbSize];
                        stream.Read(buffer, buffer.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
                        return buffer;
                    }
            }
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
アドレス計算はIntPtrを使用していると思うで32/64bitは意識する必要がないと思うのですが、どうなのでしょう？特にOLE/COMに詳しくないため、流用したコードに何か誤りがあったのかもしれません。
流用元のコードをそのままビルドしたところ、あっけなくちゃんと動いています。OutlookDataObjectという名前や名前空間を変えたりする過程で余計な事をしてしまったかもしれません。
流用元コードがちゃんと動いてますので、Seekだけ直したいと思います。ただ当方環境(Win7 64bit/VS2013Express)では正しく動いている様にみえるのですが、ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 素晴らしいコードを書いて頂き、本当に有り難うございます！
FileContentsの結果がAll 0であった要因がわかりました。
私の認識違いで、DragDropイベントにて処理すべきを、DragEnterにてテストしていたことが最大の要因でした。Evernote側はドロップされたときにFileContentsを渡してくるだろうと思いますが、それが渡される前にファイルに書き出していたようです(^_^;
本当に申し訳ありません！
書いて頂いたコードは、私が見つけたものよりずっとシンプルで分かりやすいです、非常に有用で助かります。
本当に感謝です！

Comment: Evernoteでは複数ノートを選択してエクスプローラ上にドロップすると、一つのファイルにノートがまとめて出力されます。ファイルの中身はXMLのためです。お礼をかねて書き忘れの補足ですm(__)m